# ASP.net c# page_load firing twice?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string menuIDdata = Page.Request.QueryString["mid"];
    menuID = 0;

    // Check the user is allowed here
    if (!Roles.IsUserInRole("Admin"))
    {
        Response.Redirect("../default.aspx");
    }

    // Get the menu ID
    if (int.TryParse(menuIDdata, out menuID))
    {
        menuID = int.Parse(menuIDdata);
    }
    else
    {
        menuID = 0;
    }

    debugLabel.Text = "WORKING";

    var selectedMenu = this.Page.FindControl("mnu" + menuID) as Panel;
    selectedMenu.CssClass = "navButtonO";
}
```

And on the page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="admin.aspx.cs" Inherits="*******._Default" title="Administration" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head id="mainHead" runat="server" >
        <title>Administration</title>
        <link rel="Stylesheet" href="../style/admin.css" />       
    </head>
    <body>

    <form id="mainForm" runat="server">

    <div class="topMenu">        
        <asp:Panel id="mnu0" runat="server" class="navButton">
            <a href="admin.aspx" class="navLink">Admin Home</a>
        </asp:Panel>

        <asp:Panel id="mnu1" runat="server" class="navButton">
            <a href="admin.aspx" class="navLink">User Manager</a>
        </asp:Panel>

        <asp:Panel id="mnu2" runat="server" class="navButton">
            <a href="admin.aspx" class="navLink">Products</a>
        </asp:Panel>              
    </div>                        
    <br /><br />
    <div class="subMenu">
        <a href="products.aspx" class="subLink">Products</a> <a href="productCats.aspx" class="subLink">Categories</a> 
    </div>
    <br /><br />
    Welcome to the Admin
    <br /><br />        
    <asp:label id="debugLabel" runat="server" />

    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The debug label refuses to change it's value, I'm expecting it to show "WORKING" as it's text, what am I doing wrong?

**Update:**

When attempting to build I get 3 errors:

> Error  1   Type '******._Default' already defines a member called 'Page_Load' with the same parameter types\Default.aspx.cs    12  24

x3 but on different pages

Comment: Presumably, when you debug, you can see the label text assignment line  is being hit?

Comment: I'd say that the line debugLabel.Text = "WORKING"  is never hit.

Comment: Bah, I'm opening the files in visual studio from a remote server, debug doesn't let me have permissions or something

Comment: check the html source on the browser. label is rendered as span tag.

Comment: is menuID declared at the page class level? does it redirect if you are not an admin user?

Comment: What is the value in that query string parameter?

Comment: There you go. You have to override the Page_Load on the admin page.

Comment: I'm confused, all my pages only have 1 page_load event

Comment: How do you override page_load?

Comment: Are you inheriting from the _Default page? If so, there is the Page_Load event coming from. Change the Inherits property to the Admin page.

Comment: ~Yves thank you for your help,  have no idea what the _Default page is, nor exactly how the inherits property works :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:

Ok here you go. You have a Default.aspx page that the Admin-Page most probably got copied from.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
```

So if you need some base functions from this Default-Page you need to inherit from this Page. Then change it like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="admin.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" title="Administration" %>
```

If that is not the case... (Asuming that the class of the pages is called like its file...)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="admin.aspx.cs" Inherits="Admin" title="Administration" %>
```

---

Change your code...

```
   // Get the menu ID 
if (!int.TryParse(menuIDdata, out menuID)) 
{ 
    menuID = 0; 
}
```

Since `TryParse` is returning the parsed integer with the output paramter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but still the label is displaying nothing

Comment: Even in case of unsuccess `menuID` will be 0. So if OP doesn't perform any additional action in this case, `if` isn't required at all.

Comment: Removing the roles line does nothing, it's still not showing the label.  The label is rendering as an empty <span>, but I do have 3 errors (see the edit to question), could that be stopping it running?

Answer (score 0):

Put a debugger on the code and you would see that the code never reaches the " debugLabel.Text = "WORKING";
" line of code because of some exception happening before it. There's absolutely no problem with the way you are assigning the text to label

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
string menuIDdata = Page.Request.QueryString["mid"];
menuID = 0;

// Check the user is allowed here
if (!Roles.IsUserInRole("Admin")) Then
{
    Response.Redirect("../default.aspx");
}

// Get the menu ID
if (int.TryParse(menuIDdata, out menuID))
{
    menuID = int.Parse(menuIDdata);
}
else
{
    menuID = 0;
}
}
catch { }
debugLabel.Text = "WORKING";

var selectedMenu = this.Page.FindControl("mnu" + menuID) as Panel;
selectedMenu.CssClass = "navButtonO";
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="admin.aspx.cs" Inherits="*******._Default" title="Administration" %>
```

Confuses me.  Do you have a file called admin.aspx.cs with a public class called *******._Default?  That is a very unusual convention.  Perhaps your codebehind reference or class name that this page inherits from is incorrect.

Comment: This was auto generated I think when I created the page, but I may of copied + pasted another page to make that one

Comment: Try renaming the public partial class in the admin.aspx.cs file to something unique. Then update the Inherits-"" param to the new classname. I bet at least this page will disappear from the list of compile errors.  It may or may not fix your double-postback problem.

Comment: <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="admin.aspx.cs" Inherits="Admin_Default_UNIQUE" title="Administration" %>

and in code behind:

public partial class Admin_Default_UNIQUE : System.Web.UI.Page {

Comment: Thank's for your help, I get the error:
Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'Admin_Default_UNIQUE'.

Comment: Did you also rename the classname in the admin.aspx.cs file?

public partial class Admin_Default_UNIQUE : System.Web.UI.Page {